# Fill textarea with clicked button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

SOLVED

http://jsfiddle.net/ArtofLife/u9d9d/

I have multiple TEXTAREA and BUTTON out side.. For inserting string in textarea, I used jQuery plugin (insertAtCaret). How to fill ONLY the last clicked TEXTAREA with text...?

```
<textarea name="answer_text[0]" cols="50" rows="3" style="width: 99%;">
    AAA
</textarea>

<textarea name="answer_text[1]" cols="50" rows="3" style="width: 99%;">
    BBB
</textarea>

<textarea name="answer_text[2]" cols="50" rows="3" style="width: 99%;">
    CCC
</textarea>

<textarea name="answer_text[3]" cols="50" rows="3" style="width: 99%;">
    Here should be:
    &lt;button class=insert name=insert&gt;Insert&lt;/button&gt; 
</textarea>

<button class=insert name=insert>Insert</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.fn.extend({
insertAtCaret: function(myValue) {
    return this.each(function(i) {
        if (document.selection) {
            //For browsers like Internet Explorer
            this.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
        else if (this.selectionStart || this.selectionStart == '0') {
            //For browsers like Firefox and Webkit based
            var startPos = this.selectionStart;
            var endPos = this.selectionEnd;
            var scrollTop = this.scrollTop;
            this.value = this.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + this.value.substring(endPos, this.value.length);
            this.focus();
            this.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
            this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
            this.value += myValue;
            this.focus();
        }
    });
}
});

var pos = 0;
$('textarea').click(function() {
//Get the name of this clicked item
var pos = $(this).attr("name");
$('.insert').click(function() {
    $('textarea[name^="' + pos + '"]').insertAtCaret('Actual button code');
});
return false;
});
</script>
```

Now I getting filed all the textareas that I clicked...  http://jsfiddle.net/ArtofLife/u9d9d/15/

I want to be filled only the last textarea that is clicked, and not bubbling the variable pos..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have the `.insert`'s `click` handler inside the `textarea` `click` handler. Whenever you click on `textarea` a new handler is attached and it keeps attaching as and when u click on any `textarea`. Move it outside it will work fine.

```
var pos = 0;
$('textarea').click(function() {
    //Get the name of this clicked item
    pos = $(this).attr("name");
    return false;
});
$('.insert').click(function() {
    $('textarea[name^="' + pos + '"]').insertAtCaret('Actual button code');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9d9d/17/)**